# The getter 'length' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: length Previous solutions didn't work for me

Tags: flutter

my question has definitely been asked before here but none of the solutions worked for me, hence i thought I should post my code here. I am building a todo app and Im stuck on the FutureBuilder widget I am getting the following error when running the code below. I have tried adding `"AsyncSnapshot"` in `"builder: (context, snapshot)"` but still getting the error. Could someone come to my rescue please?

`The getter 'length' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: length`

```
Expanded(
                    child: FutureBuilder(
                      initialData: [],
                      future: _dbHelper.getTasks(),
                      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                        return ScrollConfiguration(
                          behavior: NoGlowBehaviour(),
                          child: ListView.builder(
                            itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              return TaskCard(
                                title: snapshot.data[index].title,
                              );
                            },
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  )
                ],
```

Here is where the getTasks() method was initialised:

```
class DatabaseHelper {
  Future<Database> database() async {
    return openDatabase(
      join(await getDatabasesPath(), 'todo.db'),
      onCreate: (db, version) {
        // Run the CREATE TABLE statement on the database.
        return db.execute(
          'CREATE TABLE tasks(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, title TEXT, description TEXT)',
        );
      },
      version: 1,
    );
  }

  Future<void> insertTask(Task task) async {
    Database _db = await database();
    await _db.insert('task', task.toMap(),
        conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace);
  }

  Future<List<Task>> getTasks() async {
    Database _db = await database();
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> taskMap = await _db.query('task');
    return List.generate(taskMap.length, (index) {
      return Task(
          id: taskMap[index]['id'],
          title: taskMap[index]['title'],
          description: taskMap[index]['description']);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you initialise the list poroperly?

Comment: Can you please add the getTasks Method so that we can verify why the data is null.

Comment: @AnkitTale I have updated the question with how I initialised the method. is there anything wrong?

Answer (score 1):

While using `FutureBuilder` consider checking snapshot state like bellow.
It is only possible to build list with items while future done with fetching and contains data.

I prefer checking

- ConnectionState
- Error
- Data

```
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
          return Text("loassding");
        else if (snapshot.hasData &&
            snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done)
          return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                // final word = snapshot.data![index];
                print(snapshot.data!.length);
                print(snapshot.data![index].model![0].word);

                return Column(
                  children: [
                    // Text("${word.model!.length} ${word.model![0].word!}  "),
                  ],
                );
              });
        else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text(
            snapshot.error.toString(),
          );
        } else
          return Text("something else");
      },
    );
```

Does it solve in your case?

Comment: did you used `snapshot.hasData &&
            snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done`  before list, else it will go to `snapshot.hasError` . also try to print data before initList

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late reply, but your query is not returning any data because that table does not exist. You have a typo in you retrieve code. You are trying to load data from "task". The same goes for you insert function. They both need to change to change to "tasks".

in your insertTask method change the line:

```
await _db.insert('tasks', task.toMap(),
```

in your getTasks method change the line:

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> taskMap = await _db.query('tasks');
```